Saving data in a loop using Entity Framework Core
I want to save changes to the SQL table in a loop.
I have the following code:
string[] request = { "test1", "test2", "test3" };
    
TransactionData TTD = new TransactionData();
    
using (IdContext = new ProofContext())
{
    foreach (var req in request)
    {
        TTD.Description = req;
        TTD.RecordId = 12;
        TTD.PaymentStatus = "Failed";
        IdContext.TransactionData.Add(TTD);
        IdContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}

I want to save three rows in the SQL table with three different ID. The table has an identity column as its primary key. When I run my code, the changes are saved the very first time, but second time when I tried to save the changes, I got an error:

Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table TransactionData when Identity Insert is set off

Here's a screenshot for illustration:

I tried running this statement on SQL side in order to fix this error
SET IDENTITY_INSERT TransactionData ON

but still, I keep getting the error.
This is the table model:
public partial class TransactionData
{
    public int InfoId { get; set; }  // this is the identity column in the database
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal ServiceFee { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalAmount { get; set; }
    public string Sku { get; set; }
}

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

This code can never work because your IdContext doesn't have a declaration like a var or strongly typed definition. But I don't really understand what you want.

And I would suggest you use SaveChangesAsync and save everything after the for loop

@StuiterSlurf well, IdContext could have been declared outside, using(myVar = ...) is completely fine.

Bring the TransactionData TTD = new TransactionData(); inside the loop

You are adding the same TransactionData object in every pass in the loop. The first time you add it and save changes it will have identity assigned. So on the second pass you are trying to add the same one with a few properties changed. Try creating a new instance of TTD inside foreach loop

It's wonderful how healthy principles lead to other healthy coding patterns. The healthy principle is: a unit of work has one atomic commit action. (Hence the name unit of work.) In EF terms: have one SaveChanges call in one UoW.
Adhering to that principle immediately shows that calling SaveChanges inside the loop is a problem. Subsequently, solving that problem—by calling SaveChanges after the loop— shows that you can't work with one TransactionData object, because only the last iteration would be saved.
Applying the emerging patterns, a working version of your code is:
string[] request = { "test1", "test2", "test3" };

using (var idContext = new ProofContext())
{
    idContext.AddRange(request.Select(req => new TransactionData
    {
        Description = req,
        RecordId = 12,
        PaymentStatus = "Failed"
    }));
    idContext.SaveChanges();
}

As for the exception: it happens because you added a TransactionData object and saved it, by which it was assigned an id value (because if apparently has an identity column). Then the object is Add-ed again, which makes EF try to insert an object including its id value. That's impossible when IDENTITY_INSERT is OFF (but of course that shouldn't be fixed, it reveals a deeper problem).

In an ORM, an object is roughly akin to a row. If you keep giving the ORM the same object instance via Add, it will get confused as to whether you're trying to update that row vs add a new row (or similar, depending on the exact scenario).
If you intend this to be a new row/relationship: use a new object each time - and if you're adding multiple rows, let the ORM add them as a batch rather than row-by-row.
If you don't want ORM semantics: ditch the ORM for this specific job, and use a more direct tool such as Dapper (which simply executed SQL based on the object you pass in to represent parameters/arguments); since it won't be holding an object graph, it won't care if you use the same object with different values on successive calls.

You need to define Id property (or other property that you will configure as identity column).
Without it, EF mechanism is completely unable to detect whether you want to create (ID is empty) or update (ID is set to concrete value other than default).
So at first I would try updating TransactionData by adding below property
public int Id { get; set; } // as far as i see, it is autoincremented INT column

As a side note, you don't need to call SaveChanges each loop, just call it once after the loop, it will persist all changes at once.
Moreover, you should prefer SaveChangesAsync if you are inside "async enabled method" (method with signature async Task MethodName(...)).
